# Able to navigate to IIS Web Site with http but not https

Tags: http, web, iis, https

I have a website that's hosted on Windows Server 2016 on IIS. The issue I'm having is when I navigate to the webpage via https, it loads to a blank webpage. But when I navigate via http, it loads up just fine.

I've checked the bindings and it has both port 80 and 443, checked the certificate from GoDaddy, that's good until next year.

I'm not sure what else could be the issue, any thoughts?

Comment: You might try to narrow it down by running a report on the server side, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html If the server side has no issues, then move on to the browser side.

Comment: If you need more information to analyze your problem, you can use F12 to see if there are any relevant error messages in the console.

Comment: I tired JexusManager, but got stuck on trying to add the IIS server to it, I looked through the documentation, but didn't make much headway. Is it supposed to just add any existing website that's hosted on the server?

I checked F12 and in the console I get "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()        favicon.ico". I don't usually work with websites and googling this didn't come up with results that I couldn't fix. I'm wondering what resource to failed to load that https is using that http isn't.

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, try using [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/troubleshoot/iis/troubleshoot-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7) to see details about 404 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: Thank you for that tip, so I set that up and set the rule to trigger a log for any error, as I'm not sure what could be the cause. And got a bunch of logs for a  trigger status of 302 and I saw one for 404. I only found one, so it could be a red herring, but for 302, online says it's an object moved error, looking at the complete trace, it says the 302 error comes from a http status. When you navigate via http, it takes you to the site, but redirects you to the https version of the site, so is that where the 302 comes from?

Comment: If anyone has the same issue I do, I ended up having to go into IIS website, go to HTTP redirect, Check Redirect requests to this destination, and enter the https website. I also checked Only redirect requests to content in this directory (not subdirectories)

Comment: 302 will not affect the display of the page. What you need to check is the log when you access https, If you don't know how to analyze it, you can post your log to this thread.